# Unity Gameobjects look very bad quality, the lines are not straight

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, graphics, google-vr

Like the title says, I have been developing a VR app for Android in unity and I'm facing that the graphics are really low,lines are not straight and can be seen a lot of pixels.

There is a way to upgrade graphics or resolution? I have them in Tier 3

[image]

Comment: VR usually suffers from resolution limits and individual pixels are much more visible than on a standard monitor. In addition to that it appears that your grid of objects here is not flat with the viewing plane, hence the inward diagonal trend.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution is limited by your screen resolution. This is physically limit and you should understand.

**lines are not straight**: The only solution is applying Anti-Aliasing effect in post-processing, or some customise FXAA effect.

**blur graphics**: apply sharpness effect

In general, please try to apply sharpness effect first, then apply anti-aliasing effect.

But, please be noted that it will affect the performance(fps).